# React: Frequently updating a shared state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I know that redux can hold up a central store (source of truth) for the entire app. However, any change in any property requires you to clone the entire state, reflect the change and return the new state.

And I think that is too much if you are updating your app state frequently.

My problem is that I want to increment a counter component periodically in different pages. All should be in sync, therefore, they must read from the same source for their data when rendered.
The seed data will be set at the app initialization.

The source can be a Redux store. But this will create the possible issue I mentioned at the beginning.

Is there any other approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) library on your `store`. Below quote is from [this article](https://blog.rangle.io/react-and-redux-performance-with-reselect/).

> Reselect is a library for building memoized selectors. We define selectors as the functions that retrieve snippets of the Redux state for our React components. Using memoization, we can prevent unnecessary rerenders and recalculations of derived data which in turn will speed up our application.

This is an awesome library and I think it can help with your problem :)

Comment: that's interesting. But as you quoted it "prevents unnecessary rerenders and recalculations of derived data". I'm looking for a way to help me avoid cloning my State (and call mapStateToProps) too many times.
My data (counter value) does change and I need to inform all the Counter components on every change.
I just somehow need to separate my counter state from the rest.

Comment: In Reselect, if your `state` won't change, when you call `mapStateToProps` it will use the previous `props` instead of recalculate it, so it has no different with calling `(props) => { return props }` which `props` is the current `props` (so it won't rerender other components). 
Even if your `counter` changes, it is just like calling `(props) => { return { ...props, counter: props.counter + 1 } }` which won't affect your app that much (and only the components that are related to `counter` will rerender).

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using Redux in your app, I would continue to use it until you see an impact from frequently updating the store. One of the benefits of Redux is that even though you are returning a new object on every state transition, you can avoid unnecessary re-renders if your components are connected to the store properly. The default option for the [`connect`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) function is to treat the connected component as a "pure" component, meaning it won't re-render unless the specific fields selected in `mapStateToProps` change rather than rendering on any state update. That being said, there is still overhead in cloning the state object and calling all of the `mapStateToProps` functions. Without benchmarking the specific use case and frequency of updating the store it's hard to say if that overhead would be worth maintaining application state in another location.

Another option is the newly redesigned [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). It is a great way to maintain shared state without passing it all up and down your component tree. I would highly recommend reading the documentation and trying it out. Just be aware of the maintenance costs of maintaining state in multiple places and be sure to structure your app accordingly.

Comment: I'm already using redux and I'm cloning it's relatively huge state every second just for the Counter.
I have not benchmarked, but it doesn't seem right to clone the state and as you mentioned call "mapStateToProps" every second. I'll have a look at new Context API to see if it can help.

Comment: There is also a discussion on a Redux GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1303) that seems very similar to your question. It seems like the Redux authors agree that the bottleneck would be DOM updates, not Redux functions. I don't believe object cloning will be as heavy as one would think if you are only doing a shallow copy. Javascript is pretty good at managing things like that. Again, it is hard to tell without measuring. I tend to avoid optimizations that require additional maintenance until I see an impact from them, but I definitely see the concerns you have.